# Custom Solr FunctionQueries

Tags: solr, lucene, custom-component

I'm trying to implement custom Solr FunctionQueries.

I found this tutorial online http://www.supermind.org/blog/756/how-to-write-a-custom-solr-functionquery

What I need is to know if I need to change the solr source code to be able to do that or I can  write this function by reference to some solr's .jar file.

Do you know any step-by-step tutorial to do a custom solr FunctionQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not modify the Solr code.
You can implement your own Custom function Query and compile it with the Solr dependant jars.

The Custom extension classes then can be packages as separate jar file.
Command `jar -cvf ....`

This jar file can be dropped in the Solr external [shared lib](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) folder specified in Solr.xml. Solr will automatically load this folder.

Else, add in solrconfig.xml an element pointing to the dir where you have the jar

> < lib dir="directory_having_the_jar_file" />

Solr loads the external lib folder so the custom extensions are available to it.

Comment: Are you able to tell me how to do it? Any available resource on the internet?

Comment: added some steps. Not accurate though.

Comment: According to the article I need to override some functions on Solr, which packages do I need to import? Do you know?

Comment: Check any existing Function Query Solr Class and you can just rename and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this links will be helpful
http://java.dzone.com/news/how-write-custom-solr
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: That's the same article that I found.